# HTML: select menu as navigation menu

Tags: html, select

```
<select id="touchsplashmenu" onchange="window.open(this.value,'','');">
    <option value="">Choose your page</option>
    <option value="page1.html">Page 1</option>
    <option value="page2.html">Page 2</option>
    <option value="page3.html">Page 3</option>
</select>
```

Right now each page opens in a new window. How can I change this so that the page opens in the current browser window?

Comment: Hello, this is working in current browser, maybe your page url in your option value is not working or the path you are calling is wrong. can you post your pages online? or can you create your fiddle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Replace:**

```
onchange="window.open(this.value,'','');"
```

**With:**

```
onchange="window.open(this.value,'_self');"
```

Also if you are getting 404 page on "Choose your page"... Try setting it's value to `value="#"`

**Update HTML:**

```
<select id="touchsplashmenu" onchange="window.open(this.value,'_self');">
    <option value="#">Choose your page</option>
    <option value="page1.html">Page 1</option>
    <option value="page2.html">Page 2</option>
    <option value="page3.html">Page 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Corrected some typos as well :)

Answer (score 3):

Does this work for you?

```
<select id="touchsplashmenu" onchange="location.href=this.value">
    <option value="#">Choose your page</option>
    <option value="www.google.com">Page 1</option>
    <option value="www.facebook.com">Page 2</option>
    <option value="www.google.com">Page 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Works great except if you someone hits the back button and the menu doesn't rest and they select the first option it goes to a 404 page. Is there any way to add an ID to the first option and use a .not() command?

Comment: Using `location.href` is better than `window.open` because it will open in the current browser window, which was what the original questions asked for. Also, `window.open` is likely to be blocked by pop-up blockers.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<select id="touchsplashmenu" onchange="window.open(this.value,'_self');">
```

See [W3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

Comment: Thanks but the only problem it creates is that the "choose your page" option takes you to a 404 page.

Comment: You can set the Choose your page value to "#" or something similar to stay on the page.